# How To Parse A String Of Concatenated JSON In Browser?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, stream, frontend

I'm using Socket.IO to move data to the browser. The data sent is a stream of JSON objects, and when it arrives at the browser, it becomes one large string of JSON. The problem is, this JSON can't be parsed by JSON.parse() because it's not "real" JSON.

The data structure can be arbitrary so a RegEx might not do the trick. And this current setup is only temporary. Eventually this stream of JSON will be pre-processed server-side so a stream will not need to be sent to the browser, so I'd like to keep the AJAX/Socket.IO setup I have right now instead of switching over to a JSON stream parser like [OboeJS](http://oboejs.com/examples).

What can I do to parse this string of concatenated JSON?

For clarity, the JSON will look like this:

```
{"a":"A"}{"b":"B"}{"c":"C"}
```

And I'm trying to parse it in such a way that I can access them like:

```
console.log(Object.a) //A
console.log(Object.b) //B
console.log(Object.c) //C
```

Comment: Do you want to work with the data as if you received JSON? Are you sure that the data will always be in the format `{}{}{}{}`, please?

Comment: @Dropout Yes, I do. And it will always be in the format `{}{}{}{}` in that it will be concatenated JSON, but that's simplifying it. Each JSON might have nested data like `{{}{}}{}{}{}`; or there might be something like `{"a":"This is valid JSON}"}`

Comment: that's not JSON then. If you had a couple of JSONs just concatenated, you could split them and call `JSON.parse` on the array, but if you have something like {{}{}}{{{}}{}{{}}}{{}} you can't really expect it to be parsed straight away by anything really, because it's hard to apply rules to such thing. That is just garbage input data. Looks like you will have to implement something that *translates* that stuff..

Comment: are the *inner objects* in valid JSON format, true or false? Because adding a `}` to the end of a string inside JSON doesn't make it invalid. I am not considering regex approach, so it isn't an issue.

Comment: @Dropout Yes, they are all valid JSON objects inside. They're simply valid and correct JSON objects concatenated into a single string.

Comment: then why not split them and use `JSON.parse`? Something as I mentioned below: `JSON.parse("["+data.split("}{").join("},{")+"]")` as Matias mentioned?

Comment: @Dropout Because it suffers from the same drawbacks as RegEx. While unlikely, if there is something like `{"a":"This is valid JSON}{"}` in the message, the parsing will break

Comment: IMHO this problem should be resolved on the data provider's side. Try discussing the format of the data with them.. If they concatenate those objects, they are certainly able to output that array like a normal person.. I run into this problem too often, so I know it's easy to say and often not so simple to solve by negotiating with the data-providing side, so good luck!

Answer (score 2):

In your particular case, you could use `Array.prototype.reduce` to merge all JSON objects into one:

```js
var unstructuredJson = '{"a":"A"}{"b":"B"}{"c":"C"}';
var jsonArray = "[" + unstructuredJson.split("}{").join("},{") + "]";
var objectArray = JSON.parse(jsonArray);

var result = objectArray.reduce(function(result, item) {
  Object.keys(item).forEach(function(propertyName) {
    result[propertyName] = item[propertyName];
  });

  return result;
}, {});


document.body.textContent = JSON.stringify(result);
```

OP said in some comment:

> [...] Each JSON might have nested data like {{}{}}{}{}{}

Then, above approach is broken on this case.

My two cents is that you should put some separator character when you stream these JSON objects and life will be easier: you'll be able to split parent objects easily and you'll just need to change `split("}{")` with the whole separator.

I suggest you that you use some character that will never happen as part of any property value. You can find a control character on this Wikipedia article: [Control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character)

Comment: @RobG Do you mean the invalid JSON?

Comment: Exactly.. Maybe something like `JSON.parse(data.split("}{").join("},{"))`, but the inner objects need to be valid JSONs as you mentioned..

Comment: @Dropout Probably the OP has put some sample JSON done by hand, and actual JSON is valid... BTW, if OP isn't sending valid JSON, he/she should start with fixing this issue or OP will need to create a new non-JSON parser...

Comment: @RobG Let's see what OP says... Anyway, as I said in my previous comment, OP needs to adapt the code and the whole streamed string to get the desired results without re-inventing the wheel... I'll look forward for OP's comments...

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the example to be valid JSON. Yes, it's actually valid JSON, but the example was done by hand.

Comment: @markovchain Ok, I've updated my answer to drop the part where I was telling you that JSON was invalid.

Comment: @markovchain Anyway, does my answer drive you in the right direction?

Comment: I do like the suggestion to add a separator between the streams. It's easy to implement and roll back. Also the least likely to cause issues down the line :)

Comment: @markovchain Absolutely. You've many choices: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character :D

Answer (score 0):

If each substring is valid JSON but the concatenated part isn't, you can turn the string into a valid array literal and use *JSON.parse*, then you can process each object using Array methods, e.g. *forEach*:

```js
var s = '{"a":"A"}{"b":"B"}{"c":"C"}';
var obj = JSON.parse('[' + s.replace(/}{/g,'},{') + ']').forEach(function (obj) {
  document.write(JSON.stringify(obj) + '<br>');
});
```

Or if you want it as a single object:

```js
var s = '{"a":"A"}{"b":"B"}{"c":"C"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(s.replace(/}{/g,','));

document.write(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JsonParser to parse concatenated json objects:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory(mapper);

    JsonParser parser = factory.createParser(YourJsonString);
    List<YourObject> YourObjectList = new ArrayList<>();

    Iterator<YourObject> iterator = parser.readValuesAs(YourObject.class);
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        YourObject yourObject = iterator.next();
        loginSignalsList.add(yourObject);
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Split the large string `{a:'A'}{b:'B'}{c:'C'}` and parse them individually